# Missing includes in Wordpress plugin (wp_insert_post function)

Tags: wordpress, post, insert

I created a code which generates content and I want to populate Wordpress's database with it. I am using `wp_insert_post` and  `add_post_meta` functions but every time I load which triggers the script I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action() in \www\scriptmafia\wp-includes\post.php on line 153
```

To my mind it due to some missing includes. I have included post.php which it mentioned as required include for `wp_insert_post` function.

I know this is pretty common among newbies in WordPress. However, any solution I have tried have not worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-load.php'); should solve it :)

Comment: Thanks for quick response but this fix have not solved it. By the way I assumed that this snippet should be included into my module file not the post.php

Comment: My mistake this include has to be made before including post.php